# How to rearrange bootstrap grids in extra small devices

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

I have html markup like below,

```
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                    Some contents
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-12" >
                    Some Content
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-4 col-xs-12"  >
                    Some Content
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 text-right"  >
                    <div class="company-add-btn"><a href="#">+ Add more companies</a></div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

In large display's it works fine as single row structuring four divs in columns.

But in small displays I like to re-arrange the layout,

- First div will get a complete row with full width
- Third div will come before 2nd div and take a complete row with center aligned
- 2nd and 4th div will take a complete row with 2nd row stays at left, and 4th floated right.

Using bootstrap col-md-pull-* or col-md-push-* will just do the reordering inside a row. So that will not work.

One possible solution will be duplicating the markup for each media break points, but Isn't there any better approach then this ?

Can anyone suggest any way ? or point me a good place to start looking for solution ?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend (even though it's dirty) adding your view twice, once in a

```
<div class="hidden-lg hidden-md hidden-sm">Your content for the XS-grid.</div>
```

and for the other 'layout

```
<div class="hidden-xs">Your content for everything but XS-grid.</div>
```

Hope that helps (looking forward to a better solution ;)).

Answer (score 0):

what you are talking is placing third column before second column and assign it the complete width, bootstrap will not do this.

This can be done only if these columns are to be shown as a single row with pull-let and pull-right. The only option you have is to duplicate the markup in this case, or write down your own css for placing third column before the second one(but this would be not a good idea).

Answer (score 0):

You could hide the second div on small screens; the third div would then be in second position. You would then have to duplicate just the second div after the third and show on small screens only, then do the pull-left and right on the last two divs. Something similar this might work (this example is for small):

```
    <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                Some contents 1
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 hidden-sm col-xs-12" >
                Some Content 2
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" >
                Some Content 3
            </div>
            <div class="visible-sm col-sm-9 lefty" >
                Some Content 2 - duplicate
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 righty"  >
                <div class="company-add-btn"><a href="#">+ Add more companies</a></div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The use of col-xs-12 is really unnecessary in this case, and in most cases, the column will be 100% below the last col class used.

## DEMO: https://jsbin.com/nuhoba

It would be better if you had a graphic to describe what you want. If I followed correctly, then you would order your html in the order it is on a small viewport then -- if the column is in the same `.row` and the `.row` is no more than 12 columns, you can push and pull left and right. You have to add up to 12 columns per row at any given column class, I've used col-sm-X for simplicity. If you play around with col-md and/or large that means that you have to use those columns on the others but it need to add to 12 at that min-width.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-3">
         A
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-push-2 text-center-xs">
         C
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2 col-sm-pull-4">
         B
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 text-right">
         <div class="company-add-btn"><a href="#">+ D</a></div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
@media (max-width:767px) {
  .text-center-xs {text-align:center;}
 
}
```